# How to declare and assigning a variable in html template in Angular

Tags: angular

I know that the question has already asked on Stackoverflow but the proposed solutions doesn't work.

I need to loop into a list containing categories and items. I want to display only one time the category so I need to test if the category is same that the previous one.
If it's the same I don't display it but if not I display the new category. Therefore I want to declare a variable to store the current category name.

Is it possible? If not how can I do to test  previous category and new one?

Thanks

Edit :
My method to get datas :

```js
getMenuByTruck = () =>{
    const id: string = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    const apiMenu: string = environment.apiAddress + 'TruckMenu/' + id;

    this.repository.getData(apiMenu)
    .pipe(finalize(() => {
      this.updateTruckName();
    }))
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.menu = response as Menu[];
      },
      (error) =>{
        this.errorHandler.handleError(error);
        this.errorMessage = this.errorHandler.errorMessage;
      })
}
```

and my loop into html code :

```html
<div class="title" *ngFor="let m of menu">
    <h3>{{m.foodCategory?.description}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you make the category unique before display it?

Comment: Because I have several categories and I need to display categories with corresponding items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you I finaly founded a solution to my problem.
In the ts file a property category and a method:

```js
categories: string[];
...
getCats(data: Menu[]): string[]{
    return [...new Set(data.map((item) => <string>item.foodCategory?.description))];
}
```

and in the Html file this loop:

```html
<div class="title" *ngFor="let category of categories">
      <h2>Les <span>{{category}}</span></h2>
      <div *ngFor="let m of menu">
        <div *ngIf="m.foodCategory?.description == category">
          <ul>
            <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="300ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <div class="item">
             <div class="item-title">
               <span>{{m.price}} €</span>
               <h3>{{m.title}}</h3>
               <div class="border-bottom"></div>
             </div>
             <p>{{m.ingredients}}</p>
            </div>
           </li>
         </ul>   
       </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a an array of unique categories, like this:

```js
const data = [
  { category: 1, item: 'Jan' }, 
  { category: 2, item: 'Sarah' }, 
  { category: 1, item: 'Tom' },
  { category: 2, item: 'Nina'}
];

const cats = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.category))];

console.log(cats)
```

And then loop over the array of categories, using the value to filter your original data and loop over the filtered result in a nested loop.

```js
const data = [
  { category: 1, item: 'Jan' }, 
  { category: 2, item: 'Sarah' }, 
  { category: 1, item: 'Tom' },
  { category: 2, item: 'Nina'}
];

const cats = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.category))];

cats.forEach(cat => {
  console.log(cat)
  data.filter(x => x.category === cat)
    .forEach(x => console.log(x.item))
})
```

Example in angular project on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ej75fz?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

For your followup questions...

You might want to create a service to get your data to keep the request code out of your component and function:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MenuService {
  readonly API = environment.apiAddress + 'TruckMenu/'

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getData(id: string): Observable<Menu[]> {
    return this.http.get<Menu[]>(this.API + id)
  }
}
```

In your component:

```js
menus: Menu[] = []
cats: FoodCategory[] = []

constructor(
  private menuService: MenuService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ...
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.menuService.getData(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.menus = data
      this.cats = this.getCats(data)
    })
}
```

Comment: If you want me to write this out in an example angular project to help you with the template, make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and I will gladly help you out.
Another option could be to just sort the array on categories and then style your tags in the template conditionally. It kind of depends on what you are trying to achieve, so some more context in a small Stackblitz project could help.

Comment: thanks for your help. Here is an example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wrvltn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).
I want to display like this:
Catgory 1:
- Jan
- Tom
Category 2:
- Sarah
- Nina

Therefore I need to store previous category to compare with next category.

Comment: @Paintbox Here's a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4fd6b9?file=src/app/app.component.ts
You could also create a custom pipe to filter an array if you think the *ngIf is ugly.

Comment: My datas comes from a Web Api. I'm having trouble adapting you example to my case.
All the informations are in one array.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding the code.

Comment: You can just make a function to transform the data array you get from the back-end, like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ej75fz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have an error in the browser console  Can't acess property mac, data is undefined
`  getCats(data: Menu[]): FoodCategory[]{
    return [...new Set(data.map((item) => <FoodCategory>item?.foodCategory))];
  }`

Comment: You are not getting any data from the back-end, it is saying it is undefined. You want to subscribe to your request and use the data you get from the observable in the function getCats() function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237438/discussion-between-paintbox-and-h3ar7b3a7).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object type variable that will have items from original data with unique categories as key.

Suppose we have original data as

```
originalData = [
    { category: 1, item: 'Jan' },
    { category: 2, item: 'Sarah' },
    { category: 1, item: 'Tom' },
    { category: 2, item: 'Nina' },
  ];
```

We will declare a new empty object variable. Using reduce on `originalData` we will check if there is already an entry in the `acc` by key as `category` name. If it is there we will copy all those previous items (values), add a new item to it else we will just pass `currentObj` as an array.

```
itemsByCategory = {};

this.itemsByCategory = this.originalData.reduce((acc, currentObj) => {
  acc[currentObj.category] = acc[currentObj.category]
    ? [...acc[currentObj.category], currentObj]
    : [currentObj];
  return acc;
}, {});
```

getter to iterate `itemsByCategory`

```
  get categoryKeys(): string[] {
    return Object.keys(this.itemsByCategory);
  }
```

In template

```
<ul *ngFor="let key of categoryKeys">
  <li>
    Category : {{ key }}
    <p *ngFor="let obj of itemsByCategory[key]">
      {{ obj.item }}
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-au97mj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If your menu has category as object then see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-41fxp4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: This works too, I just rather use a set to get the unique categories.